# Writing Numpy Matrix to file

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a numpy matrix to a file, with each row in the matrix written to one line in the file. (eg Matrix row 1 = line 1, etc) I have tried other solutions, but when I use numpy.savetxt("myfile.txt", matrix, "%D"), it rounds all my array values to the nearest integer, which is not what I want.

If I simply write it to a file, it writes the correct numbers, but on multiple lines.

If I write this array to a file:

```
[ 0.12987668  0.74928851  0.64938338 -0.12987668 -0.74928851 -0.64938338
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.         ]
```

The output then becomes all zeros:

```
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.         
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.         ]
```

Is there anyway I can write this to a file while saving the format from the shell output?

Comment: Have you tried over `fmt`?  Explore Python % formatting docs.  Do you want the output to include `[]`?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I would like to include the [] yes. The file would only be read by humans.

Comment: `savetxt` writes a `csv` style file - neat rows and columns that `loadtxt` can load.  Can you display the array row by row using `print`?  How about using the `file` parameter with `print`?

Comment: Yes, but displaying the array row with `print()`  returns the multi-line array as written in the first array in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fmt` keyword in np.savetxt:

```
np.savetxt('FILE.txt', ARRAY, fmt='%1.8f')
```